# AirPlay 2 from guest network

Tags: network, wifi, airplay

I have two networks at home - my regular one and a guest network. My router is a Synology RT2600ac. I also have a Sonos One at home, connected to my main network.

Everything is working peachy from my main network, but I would like guests to be able to stream to the speaker as well using AirPlay 2. Naturally, though, they won't see the speaker since the guest network is not able to communicate with my main network, where the speaker is.

Is there any way to set this up? Any sort of port forwarding or setting on the router to allow this sort of communication?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm afraid this cannot be done without eliminating the whole point to having a separate guest Network. On the other hand, I highly doubt that a Sonos supports multiple IPs. Your best bet at this point might be something like a 3.5mm/optical (?) jack connected Raspberry Pi running OSMC or a Windows/macOS machine running headless (or not) with Reflector 3 to act as server with double IPs. It would most likely end up being more of a PITA than anything. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the response! That’s a pitty to hear. I’m currently in contact with Synology support and I still hope I can figure this out. Turns out the Sonos is in fact reachable from my guest network (can be pinged), the only problem seems to be that the broadcast packets for discovery are not routed from the guest to the main network. So I believe there might still be hope after all... . If not, as you said, everything else is pretty much too much of a pain :/

Comment: AirPlay uses a discovery technology called Bonjour that - as you mentioned - needs some packets to be broadcasted to hosts. These packages include info such like MAC Address etc... And these protocols can be quite finicky if you are in an unusual network configuration. I am more or less in the same boat.